# What is the word(s) used to describe when someone disappear in front of you?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I've seen such word once, and i can't remember it. This word is used to describe when someone disappear in front of another one.

It is kinda like "fade". It can also be a phrasal verb, for i'm not quite sure if it is a single word.

Can you help me? Give me some suggestions, please! Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Disappear* works for your question as written, as does *fade*. What other qualities are you looking for in this word?

Comment: Requests to help you remember something you’ve forgotten are off topic. This is what we call a "guessing game" question. They're not a good fit for the site – or, to my knowledge, any SE site. See: [Let’s Play The Guessing Game – Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From your question:
1. Disappear
2. Fade

My answer:
Vanished

Comment: "Vanish into thin air", that's what i was looking for and your answers helped a lot! Thank you!